# maintain single database between customer and seller of android app

Tags: java, android, sqlite

If the customer places their order an app, it affects the SQLite database in their phone and I think the SQLite database is separate for every phone.
Then how can I get their order in the seller's phone app?
Can I use other than SQLite for maintain one database?

Comment: You'll need to create some sort of backend that syncs all this.

Answer (score 0):

You must use online databases.

Examples:

- Firebase Realtime Database
- Firebase Firestore
- Azure SQL Database

Or you can host a database & server to serve your requirements.